# How can I for example list five largest files in /usr/lib -directory?

Tags: files, find, directory, ls

How can I for example list five largest files in `/usr/lib` directory?

Please also add some minor explanation for each bit of code that you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest would be to simply sort by size and print the last 5 lines:

```
ls -Sr /usr/lib | tail -n 5
```

From `man ls`:

```
   -r, --reverse
          reverse order while sorting
   -S     sort by file size
```

`tail` just prints the last N lines of a file:

```
   -n, --lines=K
          output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to
          output lines starting with the Kth
```

If you also want to check for files in subdirectories, you could do this:

```
find /usr/lib -type f -ls | sort -gk7 | tail -n 5
```

The `find` command looks for files, from `man find`:

```
   -type c
          File is of type c:
          [ ... ]
          f      regular file
   -ls    True;  list  current file in ls -dils format on standard output.
          The block counts are of 1K blocks, unless the environment  vari‐
          able  POSIXLY_CORRECT  is set, in which case 512-byte blocks are
          used.  See the UNUSUAL FILENAMES section for  information  about
          how unusual characters in filenames are handled.
```

`sort` does what you would expect, it sorts its input. From `man sort`:

```
   -g, --general-numeric-sort
          compare according to general numerical value
   -k, --key=KEYDEF
          sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
```

So, sort `-g` makes it sort in numerical order and `-k7` makes it sort on the 7th field which, in the case of `find -ls`, is the size of the file.

This should be relatively robust and have no problems with file names with spaces or weird characters. In any case, since you are searching through `/usr/lib` it is unlikely that you will have strange file names.

Comment: ok thank you but could you please give me some explanation so I could explore further? thank's

Comment: I know what pipe lines do but for instance what does tail -n 5 means and does exactly?

Comment: @cash see updated answer.

Comment: @cash you're welcome. If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score -1):

ls -lSr | tail -5
This will work

-r for reverse 
-l for long listing
-S is the option to sort file size wise.